# Create a record in Google contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am trying to send a post request to create a record in Google contacts from my app and I am sending the "name" field in the request body as below.

```
-(void)exportGoogleContact:(NSString*)name {

CLNetworkDataModel *dataModel = [[CLNetworkDataModel alloc] init];
dataModel.httpMethod = eNetworkOperationTypePost;

NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *token = [data stringForKey:@"Accesstoken"];
NSLog(@"token is %@",token);

dataModel.apiUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact?access_token=%@",token];
NSString * requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@",name];

dataModel.requestParams = requestString;
CLNetworkOperation *uuidOperation = [CLNetworkOperation operationForTarget:self callBackSelector:@selector(exportGoogleReponseData:)
                                                                 dataModel:dataModel];

[[CLGlobalNetworkQueue sharedInstance] addOperation:uuidOperation];
  }
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
 {
 "error": {
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"name\": 
  Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'name' could not be found in 
request message.",
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"details": [
  {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations": [
      {
        "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"name\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field 'name' could not be found in request message."
      }
    ]
  }
]
         }
 }
```

Anyone have idea, how to fix the this error, Thanks in advance

Comment: Which documentation are you following?

Comment: I followed https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact

Comment: I solved that above issue in my question.Now I am able create the record successfully in Google contacts.

Comment: @iVJ Can you please elaborate how did you solve the problem, either update the question with a solution or you can answer your own question too.

Comment: @ViralSavaj Just follow the documentation link that I provided , Create same Json format as they shown there, you will get to know and you can test API also there itself

Comment: @iVJ It gives the same error you receive, we have added two params, displayName and Familyname, later add that dictionary to the array, and put it for Names keyword, still it gives the same error. Can you please post your code here if possible

Comment: @ViralSavaj please check  the code which was working for me in my answer. hope it will you  help to get solution for your problem

Comment: @ViralSavaj have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full code which is working fine for me

```
 // Export to Google contacts

 -(void)exportGoogleContact:(NSString*)name mobile:(NSString *)mobile phone: 
 (NSString *)phone email:(NSString*)email company:(NSString *)company 
 designation: 
 (NSString *)designation website:(NSString *)website address:(NSString 
 *)address 
 notes:(NSString*)notes {
CLNetworkDataModel *dataModel = [[CLNetworkDataModel alloc] init];
dataModel.httpMethod = eNetworkOperationTypePostJson;
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *token = [data stringForKey:@"Accesstoken"];
NSLog(@"token is %@",token);

NSMutableDictionary * reqDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[reqDict setObject:name forKey:@"Name"];
[reqDict setObject:mobile forKey:@"MobileValue"];

[reqDict setObject:phone forKey:@"PhoneValue"];

[reqDict setObject:email forKey:@"EmailValue"];
[reqDict setObject:company forKey:@"CompanyValue"];
[reqDict setObject:designation forKey:@"DesignasionValue"];
[reqDict setObject:website forKey:@"WebsiteValue"];
[reqDict setObject:address forKey:@"AddressValue"];

if([notes  isEqual: @""]){

    notes = @"Added through APPName";
}

[reqDict setObject:notes forKey:@"NotesValue"];


    dataModel.apiUrl = [NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people:createContact? 
access_token=%@",token];
//NSString * requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@",name];
NSString *requestString = [CLUtils createJsonContentForGoogleSync:reqDict];
dataModel.requestParams = requestString;
CLNetworkOperation *uuidOperation = [CLNetworkOperation operationForTarget:self 
callBackSelector:@selector(exportGoogleReponseData:)

dataModel:dataModel];

[[CLGlobalNetworkQueue sharedInstance] addOperation:uuidOperation];
}
```

//Here is the code to create json request

```
 + (NSString *) createJsonContentForGoogleSync:(NSDictionary *)reqDict{

NSMutableDictionary *phoneDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *phoneDataDict2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *phoneDataDict3 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *phoneDataDict4= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *phoneDataDict5 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *phoneDataDict6 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSMutableDictionary *companyDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *emailDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *designatioDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *websiteDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *nameDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *mobileDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *addressDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *notesDataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];




[nameDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"Name"] forKey:@"givenName"];
[websiteDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"WebsiteValue"] 
forKey:@"value"];
//[designatioDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"DesignasionValue"] 
forKey:@"value"];
[emailDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"EmailValue"] forKey:@"value"];
[designatioDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"DesignasionValue"] 
forKey:@"title"];
[companyDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"CompanyValue"] 
forKey:@"name"];

[mobileDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"MobileValue"] 
forKey:@"value"];
[mobileDataDict setObject:@"mobile" forKey:@"type"];

[phoneDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"PhoneValue"] forKey:@"value"];
[phoneDataDict setObject:@"work" forKey:@"type"];

NSArray *companyArry;
if(![[companyDataDict objectForKey:@"name"]  isEqual: @""]){
companyArry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:companyDataDict, 
designatioDataDict,nil];
}

else{

    [companyDataDict setObject:@" " forKey:@"name"];
    companyArry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:companyDataDict, 
designatioDataDict,nil];

}
NSArray *phoneNosArry;
phoneNosArry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mobileDataDict,phoneDataDict,nil];

if([reqDict.allKeys containsObject:@"PhoneValue2"]){
    [phoneDataDict2 setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"PhoneValue2"] 
forKey:@"value"];
    [phoneDataDict2 setObject:@"work" forKey:@"type"];
    phoneNosArry = [NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:mobileDataDict,phoneDataDict,phoneDataDict2 ,nil];

}
if([reqDict.allKeys containsObject:@"PhoneValue3"]){

    [phoneDataDict3 setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"PhoneValue3"] 
forKey:@"value"];
    [phoneDataDict3 setObject:@"work" forKey:@"type"];
    phoneNosArry = [NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:mobileDataDict,phoneDataDict,phoneDataDict2,phoneDataDict3 
,nil];


    }

    if([reqDict.allKeys containsObject:@"PhoneValue4"]){
        [phoneDataDict4 setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"PhoneValue4"] 
forKey:@"value"];
[phoneDataDict4 setObject:@"work" forKey:@"type"];
phoneNosArry = [NSArray 


    }
    if([reqDict.allKeys containsObject:@"PhoneValue5"]){
        [phoneDataDict5 setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"PhoneValue5"] 
forKey:@"value"];
        [phoneDataDict5 setObject:@"work" forKey:@"type"];
        phoneNosArry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mobileDataDict,phoneDataDict,phoneDataDict2,phoneDataDict3,phoneDataDict4,phoneDataDict5 ,nil];

    }

        if([reqDict.allKeys containsObject:@"PhoneValue6"]){
        [phoneDataDict6 setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"PhoneValue6"] forKey:@"value"];
        [phoneDataDict6 setObject:@"work" forKey:@"type"];

            phoneNosArry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:mobileDataDict,phoneDataDict,phoneDataDict2,phoneDataDict3,phoneDataDict4,phoneDataDict5,phoneDataDict6 ,nil];

        }
//[phoneDataDict addEntriesFromDictionary:mobileDataDict];
[addressDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"AddressValue"] forKey:@"formattedValue"];
[notesDataDict setObject:[reqDict objectForKey:@"NotesValue"] forKey:@"value"];


[notesDataDict setObject:@"TEXT_PLAIN" forKey:@"contentType"];



NSMutableDictionary *parentDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[parentDict setObject:nameDataDict forKey:@"names"];
[parentDict setObject:emailDataDict forKey:@"emailAddresses"];
[parentDict setObject:companyArry forKey:@"organizations"];
[parentDict setObject:websiteDataDict forKey:@"urls"];
 // [parentDict setObject:designatioDataDict forKey:@"occupations"];
//[parentDict setObject:phoneDataDict forKey:@"phoneNumbers"];
[parentDict setObject:phoneNosArry forKey:@"phoneNumbers"];
//[parentDict setObject:mobileDataDict forKey:@"phoneNumbers"];
[parentDict setObject:addressDataDict forKey:@"addresses"];
[parentDict setObject:notesDataDict forKey:@"biographies"];
NSData *resultData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parentDict 
options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *jsonString ;
if(resultData != nil){
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:resultData 
encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
NSLog(@"####### Final json string is %@",jsonString);
return jsonString;

}
```